# Update g++ but still old version

Tags: c++, g++, upgrade

I installed g++ using those commands line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.1 
sudo apt-get update
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-7 g++-7
```

When it was done I tried `g++ -v` but still shows me the old version

```
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
```

Am I not upgrading it correctly?

**Edit**

```
:~$ dpkg -L g++-7

/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/gcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/cc1plus
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/gcc-7-base
/usr/share/doc/gcc-7-base/C++
/usr/share/doc/gcc-7-base/C++/README.C++
/usr/share/doc/gcc-7-base/C++/changelog.gz
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-7.1.gz
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-7
/usr/share/doc/g++-7
/usr/share/man/man1/g++-7.1.gz
/usr/bin/g++-7


:~$ which g++

/usr/bin/g++
```

Comment: try this command to check if it is there `apt-cache search gcc-7` then do `sudo apt install gcc-7`

Comment: @PeterHaddad Yes it is and then it said gcc-7 is already the newest version (7.1.0-5ubuntu2~16.04). But still `g++ -v` shows the older version

Comment: Try running `which g++` and seeing where the shell *thinks* g++ is, and compare this to where `apt-get` installed it to. Also try running eg. `g++-7 --version` to see if it's been installed under a postfixed name.

Comment: @hnefatl I edited my question and  `g++-7 --version` shows  `g++-7 (Ubuntu 7.1.0-5ubuntu2~16.04) 7.1.0`

Comment: Okay, last thing then is `dpkg -L g++-7`. Then we know where the "system version" of g++ is (the out of date one) and where the new version is.

Comment: @hnefatl just edited my question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Installing a newer (or older) version of GCC than the Ubuntu default version via the package manager
does not delete the default version. You get both. You can install as many
versions as you like. `gcc/g++` will continue
to run the default version. If you have installed GCC 7, then you run
the new compilers with `gcc-7` or `g++-7`. For most build systems, it is sufficient to set the environment variables `CC=gcc-7 CXX=g++-7` before starting the build.

Comment: I installed g++ 7 following instructions from here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/859256/how-to-install-gcc-7-or-clang-4-0 and configured the environment variable as stated my Mike. But when I do 'g++ --version' , I still get the older version . Any ideas ?

Comment: @gajendra The last sentence of my answer applies to *build systems*. You are not using one. You are simply running `g++` by hand. So run `g++-7 --version`.

Answer (score 3):

I installed the gcc-7 using the directions given in [Ubuntu Forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859256/how-to-install-gcc-7-or-clang-4-0), rebooted the system (to make sure all environment variables are loaded) and to compile with C++ 17, type the following on the shell :
`g++-7 -std=c++17 program_name.cpp -o program.out`

Hope this helps.